# Add Status using Facebook API

Tags: web-services, rest, facebook-graph-api

I am learning Rest web services using Postman extension of Chrome. I'm practicing it using Facebook API. I have a question about posting in FB.

URI used: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?

In the Body of the POST Method, I have given the following Json content

```
  {   
     "message": "hello",  
     "access_token": "<a valid token>"
  }
```

I am very sure that my access token is correct as when I append the access token and message with the above URI, the status gets posted successfully. Also when I use it as key-value pairs in 'x-wwww-form-urlencoded' section, it works fine.

But when I try to update the status using the Body of the POST method with the JSON content mentioned above, it tells

```
 { "error": { "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 2500 } }
```

Is there any thing wrong in the format of the JSON content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed content-type=application/json 
in the Header section.

Adding this solved the problem